# Kubuntu 14.10 crashing frequently

Tags: kubuntu, kde, 14.10, freeze, crash

I have installed Kubuntu 14.10 on my new laptop, and have been using for past couple of weeks. It's a Dell Inspiron 7537, the 16 GB variant.

It's happening very frequently (3 to 4 times a day) that I am in the middle of something, and the whole thing just freezes. The cursor cannot move. Keyboard, touchpad don't work. Ctrl+Alt+Bkspc does nothing. (**Update:** Just discovered this doesn't restart the X-server by default.) I was hard-resetting my machine first few times, but then I found out that that Ctrl+Alt+F1 works and I have been `sudo reboot`ing since, which seems like a more graceful way to do it.

What could be causing these frequent freezes? Can I get a debug dump of the crash somewhere? Also as a temporary solution, is there a way to avoid rebooting the whole system?

Comment: if you can `Ctrl+Alt+F1` to get a command line, run `top` to see what process is hogging the cpu. You can `kill -1` each process and try `Ctrl+Alt+F8` (I think F8 means X-windows) to see if it unlocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening to my Lenovo T510 with Kubuntu 14.10 as well, several times every day. Ctrl+Alt+F1 followed by Ctrl+Alt+F7 "unfreezes" KDE, so no need to reboot for me. It's very annoying, though.

Comment: Hi Ari. I have been using the same work-around. Yes, that does it, but as you said, it is annoying.